# Ending a mail in my language?

Tags: word-choice, business-language

I was having a discussion with my coworker because I was sending a mail in English (we're Mexicans), and I wanted to end the mail with:

`Saludos!`

My coworker insisted that I ought to stick to the language of the rest of the email and end it with:

`Regards`

or something like that.

I know that in our country we are less formal than workers in the USA, and I kind of want to still be achieve a mix of laid back style while keeping a formal tone. My question is, do you feel that this is a bad idea in a work situation?

Saludos!

Comment: I'm voting to close this and suggest it gets migrated to [The Workplace SE site](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Inserting foreign words into text is called **Macaronic** , and was popular in the Elizabethan court. There also it was a sign of culture and education.

Comment: I think it adds a bit of spice to email communication. Nothing wrong with it in my opinion if its not a highly formal email where you should stick with a more conventional sign-off.

Comment: Ciao Tono -- I definitely agree it's a good idea, it's cool.  Cordialement!

Answer (score 1):

It is a common occurrence to end a letter or an e-mail in your own language and although it can be used in both a formal and informal contexts, using a salutation such as *Saludos!* would be seen as a more friendly gesture which should be used with someone who you already know (i.e. a friend or a co-worker).

However, if this letter is directed to an important person (i.e. your boss), I'd suggest using an English salutation to achieve 'maximum formality'.